# scraping and graphing views over time

Tags: python, sql, django, sqlite, web-scraping

Context: I'm messing around in Django

I have a working webscraper that can get the link, title and number of views from a youtube video, and add this information to an sqlite database. What id like to be able to do is run this say once every hour and be able to display a graph of the views over time. Right now I only have one table in my database, which may be fine for one video but im assuming if i want to track multiple videos id need a different model.

My best guess for how to make this scale would be to have a table for just the videos i want to monitor and then each scraping event log the id of the video, the datetime and the views in another table. But if im scraping a bunch of videos data id be storing basically the same datetime every batch (as long as it takes less than an hour per batch)

I would appreciate it if you could point me in the correct direction for the following issues:

Is that two table data model correct/scalable enough? 
Easy way to do change over time math/ graph with the data?
Best practice for triggering a scraper like clockwork?

Answer (score 0):

maybe storing your main data in a dictionary might be a first start. That way you link videoID to Views for quick access. Using the videoID you of course could trigger unique fields in whatever database. 
If you'd go this way you also might want to look at python's pickle module.
[Python object serialization](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) 
Have a look on a first idea how to use the idea on dictionaries:
[Using Pickle](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle)
There is a great overview on how to use and when to use it:
[python pickle vs sql efficiency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16497115/python-pickle-vs-sql-efficiency)

Hope this will help you as you asked for a personal hint.

Comment: thank you, I had not yet come across pickle, think I will be able to make it work for me, at the very least it will be another good learning experience